# Reference to a table that is defined by two Primary keys in sequelize typescript + PostgreSQL

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I seen many old post (without answer) from 2015 that talk about this problems but not for the typescript version of sequelize.

I have 3 classes: `Users`,  `Technos`, `Projects`

I want several Users in Projects BUT each users can use several technos in that projects. To have this information I thought about two Association-Table linked to each-other:

1. ProjectsInstances-Users: ForeignKey Users + ForeignKey ProjectsInstances (This works)
2. ProjectsInstances-Users-Technos: ForeignKey ProjectsInstances-Users + ForeignKey Technos (DOES NOT WORK)

[image]

In this second case, I can't define a reference to ProjectsInstances-Users because it is defined by TWO ForeignKeys so this does not work:

```
@Table
export class ProjectsInstancesUsersTechnos extends Model{

  // FOREIGN KEYS --------------------------------------------

  // Users
  @ForeignKey(() => ProjectsInstancesUsers)
  @Column
  projectsInstancesUsersId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => ProjectsInstancesUsers)
  projectsInstancesUsers: Users;

  // Users
  @ForeignKey(() => Technos)
  @Column
  technosId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Technos)
  technos: Technos;

  }
```

I obviously have:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "ProjectsInstancesUsers"

How can I define a set of several primary keys to make a reference to ProjectsInstancesUsers ?